# tense of that-clause in conditional

Tags: conditionals, sequence-of-tenses

I was writing a comment under a video about a series which I used to watch ten years ago. I was writing that if I were watching them for the first time today, I would not enjoy as much as I did years ago.

My exact words were:

> I can't say I would be as enthusiastic about watching them now as I used to be ten years ago, if it were for the first time that I ___ watching.

I was stuck at the blank part as to what helping verb I should use. Perhaps intuitively I chose **was** or because to make my sentence tense-consistent.

But I am still confused that why **were** can't be used as the whole scenario is a hypothetical and watching the series now would be a hypothetical one too, just like in the first paragraph "...if I were watching them..." as there i didn't confuse in **was** or **were**.?
and why not 'am'?

Comment: I agree, a second 'were' sounds weird, while I usually stick to 'if it were'. I'd say that someone will come up with a prescriptive rule here which 75+% of seasoned native speakers prove isn't a rule by not following it.

Comment: Using "if it were" is certainly unusual in speech or casual writing - I'd prefer something like "if I was watching for the first time", or in formal writing the more elegant "were I watching for the first time". But "was" doesn't sound quite right to me in the original sentence. I'm kind of tempted to say it should be "that I be watching" but I don't have any actual evidence or reason for that.

Comment: Tenses in counterfactuals and hypotetheticals like this are often tricky. Don't worry about it in casual conversation.

Comment: @StuartF Maybe in the UK it would be unusual in speech, but it's completely normal in America among educated speakers.

Comment: Come now, if it/that were true, I would not be commenting on it.//if this was the first time I was watching *them*.

Comment: @StuartF That construction only occurs in formal writing? Somebody tell [Beyoncé.](https://youtube.com/watch?v=AWpsOqh8q0M&pp=ygUPSWYgSSB3ZXJlIGEgYmx5)